# Distribute pre-built native binaries in npm

Tags: node.js, binary, npm, native

Is it possible to distribute pre-built native binaries using npm and where can I find any documentation on this topic ?

Answer (score 5):

After spending some additional time, I found a `node-pre-gyp` module that seems to do what you (and me) want: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp.

The module page has links to an FAQ and sample on GitHub. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to distribute your Node.js application as a binary that contains node and your dependencies, there are a few options I am aware of:

- [Nexe](https://github.com/nexe/nexe)
- [pkg](https://github.com/zeit/pkg), which does not (yet) work with Node 11
- [EncloseJS](http://enclosejs.com/) - no longer maintained